# This code always returns Image not loaded, is the path correct .this is opencv in android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_weiss_konrad_arrowapp_NDKInterface_getID(JNIEnv *env, jobject o ){
    Mat img =  imread("storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160506_141333.jpg");
    if(img.empty())                             
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF("Image not loaded");
    }

    return env->NewStringUTF("Image loaded");
}
```

Comment: You might be missing a `/` at the beginning of the path.  Without it's is probably a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Different devices may use different paths to store the camera pictures. You must use [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) to find the correct path (sometimes it can even be changed by the end-user). I understand that it is a burden to find call this function from C++, so probably you will find it easier to pass this path from Java.